# Different result between highlight and filter Power BI Desktop

Tags: filter, report, powerbi, highlight, interaction

I just noticed something that I can't explain. I have a simple table visual that has an interaction with a bar chart. When I click on the table, the bar chart is then "filtered". Nothing special for now. But the result is not the same if I choose to filter on the visual or to highlight on it. So when I choose the Filter icon above the bar chart, the result is different than if I choose the Highlight icon. Do you have any idea why it happen ? Because I'm pretty sure it should not be.

Here is a picture to explain my problem : [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect the result to be the same? These are two distinct options. Filtering removes everything but what you've selected whereas highlighting just fades out everything else.

Comment: Well, I understand it should not be the same on the visual but the result of the measure should be the same.